# Adding multiple validations to single column of excel using POI library(java)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to add multiple validation to single column of a excel sheet. For example,
There is a email id column . First of all i want to check that if it is empty then i want to check that if it is valid email id. I am using below code to check both. But it's not working.

```
    XSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
    XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint111 = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper.createCustomConstraint(
            "=COUNTA($C$2:C2)>ROW()-2");
    CellRangeAddressList addressList111 = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 9, 2, 2);
    XSSFDataValidation validation111 = (XSSFDataValidation) dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint111, addressList111);
    validation111.setShowErrorBox(true);
    validation111.createErrorBox("Warning!!!", "Empty cells not allowed for Email column");
    sheet.addValidationData(validation111);

    XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper.createCustomConstraint(
            "=AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(\"@\",C1))),NOT(ISERROR(FIND(\".\",C1))),ISERROR(FIND(\" \",C1)))");
    CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 9, 2, 2);
    XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation) dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
    validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
    validation.createErrorBox("Warning!!!", "Please enter valid email id");
    sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

Comment: Please try achieving this in `Excel`s GUI. You will fail since a cell can have exactly *one* data validation set. So the only way is combining both the formulas into one data validation. While `apache poi` sometimes seems to be magic software, it cannot perform magic (until now). It cannot do what `Excel`itself cannot do.

Comment: Could you please help me to combine these formulas.. after that i will try for other formulas too.